# react-native-video doesn't take the remote url

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

In my application, I use react-native-player library. I have included it inside a component and source uri is set via a prop.

```
let video = trainingProgress.currentMovementVideo;

            <View style={styles.movementContainer}>
                <CurrentMovement   
                    movementName={trainingProgress.currentMovementName}
                    movementVideo={video}
                    // movementVideo="https://finess-dev.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/workouts/movements/1f6cca50-ba55-11e8-a6f9-2961a9ae2944lion-sample.mp4"
                    reps={trainingProgress.currentMovementReps}
                />
            </View>
```

here in the currentMovement component, movement video is similar in both cases.

```
 movementVideo={video}
 // movementVideo="https://finess-dev.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/workouts/movements/1f6cca50-ba55-11e8-a6f9-2961a9ae2944lion-sample.mp4"
```

both values are same, but the player takes only the hardcoded value. The same value which is coming from database is not taken as the video url.

What should I do to overcome this issue?